# R Regex number followed by punctuation followed by space

Tags: regex, r

Suppose I had a string like so:

```
x <- "i2: 32390. 2093.32: "
```

How would I return a vector that would give me the positions of where a number is followed by a `:` or a `.` followed by a space?

So for this string it would be

```
"2: ","0. ","2: "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex you need is just `'\\d[\\.:]\\s'`. Using `stringr`'s `str_extract_all` to quickly extract matches:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all("i2: 32390. 2093.32: ", '\\d[\\.:]\\s')
```

produces

```
[[1]]
[1] "2: " "0. " "2: "
```

You can use it with R's built-in functions, and it should work fine, as well.

What it matches:

- `\\d` matches a digit, i.e. number
- `[ ... ]` sets up a range of characters to match

  - `\\.` matches a period
  - `:` matches a colon
- `\\s` matches a space.

Comment: True. I wanted to keep it basic, though, and escaping the period works regardless of the context.

Comment: Or using base `regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\d[:.]\\s", x))`

Comment: Also true. I wasn't sure whether the original wanted to match any space or just " "; `'\\d[:.] '` would match more narrowly.